# C# regex replacement - not able to use matched variables

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use regex in C# to edit string format.

Previous format is 09/08/2015 or 9/08/2015 and pattern I tried is `"([0-9]{1,}|[0-9]{2,})/[0-9]{2,}/[0-9]{4,}"`
New format should be 2015 08 09

I am trying to use variables from match, but it shows only $1 and not $2 or $3

```
string pattern = "([0-9]{1,}|[0-9]{2,})/[0-9]{2,}/[0-9]{3,}";
string replacement = "$3 $2 $1";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(text, replacement);
richTextBox1.Text = result;
```

Please, help me to edit proper pattern format.

**EDIT:**
I just forget to write, that at first I am loading data from .txt file and in that data I am replacing date format `31/03/2015` or `1/03/02` to `2015 03 31`.

Comment: Do not use regex to manipulate dates (too hard), much easier to parse and then format. "Previous format is 09/08/2015 or 9/08/2015": you mean you want to support both "dd/MM/yyyy" and "MM/dd/yyyy"? If so better to use examples that are not ambiguous.

Comment: @juharr If you're only converting strings to another format, why would you convert it into another representation, just to output it back as strings? If it's never used as a DateTime, or no validation is needed, no point in converting back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your regex has only one matching group. A correct one would be `([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})`.

The parentheses are used to mark the groups and you only marked the first one with them. Also your regexp is a bit incorrect, since it would also match 832947928/8237549875923/9999, which probably is not what you need.

In this form, it wants one or two numbers, slash, two numbers, slash and four numbers and does the conversion.

Note that using `[0-9]{1,2}` will allow invalid dates also, so it's not suitable for validation. Only for this conversion.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of regex, how about parsing them to `DateTime` and get their string representation with specific format? (*I assumed your 09 is day number*)

```
string s = "9/08/2015";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "d/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    dt.ToString("yyyy MM dd").Dump(); // 2015 08 09
}
```

or

```
string s = "09/08/2015";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    dt.ToString("yyyy MM dd").Dump(); // 2015 08 09
}
```

Or [`DateTime.TryParseExact` has an overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes format part as a string array which you can supply multiple formats.

```
var formats = new[] {"d/MM/yyyy", "d/MM/yyyy"};
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                             DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    dt.ToString("yyyy MM dd").Dump(); // 2015 08 09
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Much easier approach is to use .NET's inbuilt parser for dates. This will also ensure that invalid inputs like "99/99/0001" will fail.

```
DateTime res;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, new [] {"dd/MM/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy"}, applicableCultureInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out res)) {
  return res.ToString("yyyy MM dd");
} else {
  throw InvalidArgumentException("Unsupported date format");
}
```