# C# regex - check/edit matching group before using

Tags: c#, regex

I have a problem with editing regex matching group.

I want to check if in the last matching group is 1 or 2 digit and if there is 1 digit, add 0 before it.

Example in code: 9/05/2015
Example I want:  2015 05 09

Code:

```
string line;
string pattern = "([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})";
string replacement = "$3 $2 $1";

System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
   string result = rgx.Replace(line, replacement);
   all += result + "\r\n";
   richTextBox1.Text += result + "\r\n";
}
```

Thank you for a help

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = textBox1.Text;
            string newFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("d-M-yyyy hh,mm,ss");
            textBox2.Text = "data-"+newFileName+".txt";
            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);

            string line;
            string pattern = "([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})";
            string replacement = "$3 $2 $1";

            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
                string result = rgx.Replace(line, replacement);
                all += result + "\r\n";
                richTextBox1.Text += result + "\r\n";
            }

            file.Close();
        }
```

FILE LOOKS LIKE:

```
ACD 000     9/04/2015   14:00 



REPT 1
ACD      AVG CALLS       AVG  AVG  AVG  AVG  AVG    DN  AVG   #-XFER  AVG-TIME-POSN 
 DN     AGTS ANSWD  ASA  DCP HDCP  PCP WORK WAIT CALLS TIME  IDN  ACD   BUSY MANNED
7777       1     3   15   91    0   82  173  477     4   96    0    0    453   1169 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1              3   15   91    0   82  173  477     4   96    0    0    453   1169 


REPT 2
ACD     CALLS  RECALL ANSWERED  ABANDONED      TOF TOF  OVER    INTER  
 DN    ACCPTED  TO    LONGEST   NO. AVG.WT TSF IN  OUT  FLOW    FLOW   
               SOURCE WT. TIME                                  BUSY
7777         3      0       32    0  ****   66   0   0     0       0 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1          3      0       32    0  ****   66   0   0     0       0 

        CALLS    CALLS ANSWERED      ABANDONED        ROUTE               DFLT
CDN    ACCPTED   NO.  ASA  LONG WT   NO. AVG.WT TSF     BY     DISC BUSY   DN 
                                                     IVR  CCR 
8830         0     0 ****        0     0  ****    0    0    0     0    0    0
```

Comment: You asked _almost_ the same question today http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607176/c-sharp-regex-replacement-not-able-to-use-matched-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DateTime is the correct option. Just as an option, you could parse the string to int, and pad the zeros with [`:Dn` notation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in `string.Format()` (it is safe since you only capture digits in the first group):

```
// Declare somewhere before, better as a private readonly field
private readonly Regex rgx = new Regex("([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

and then, inside the caller:

```
var line1 = "9/05/2015";
if (rgx.IsMatch(line1))
{
    var result = string.Format("{0} {1} {2:D2}", rgx.Match(line1).Groups[3].Value, rgx.Match(line1).Groups[2].Value, Int32.Parse(rgx.Match(line1).Groups[1].Value));
}
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT**

I'd suggest using `using` when reading a file, it will free resources more gracefully. And here is my implementation:

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path))
{
   while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
       // Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern); // DECLARE IT BEFORE WITH Compiled OPTION
       Match m = rgx.Match(line);
       if (m.Success)
       {
           string result = string.Format("{0} {1} {2:D2}", m.Groups[3].Value, m.Groups[2].Value, Int32.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value));
           all += line.Replace(m.Value, result) + "\r\n";
           richTextBox1.Text += line.Replace(m.Value, result) + "\r\n";
       }
       else
       {
           all += line + "\r\n"; 
           richTextBox1.Text += line + "\r\n";
       }
   }
   file.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am fetching whole file, where are different dates. Example 11/05/2015, 12/12/2001 etc.. There can not be fixed line1

Comment: Sure, it is not "fixed", I used the text from your example as an example :).

Comment: And in result var will be whole line with replaced date or only date? :)

Comment: One line consists of a lot of words and there is a date... In var result I want  whole words with replaced date :(

Comment: You ask about the final result, right? You can just use `line.Replace(rgx.Match(line).Value, result)`.

Comment: No, the file consists of many rows with many words, numbers etc and sometime there is a date in that format. I want to replace that via the 2015 02 01 everywhere and save the same format /brakes rows etc/ to .txt.

Comment: I updated my code. Output first line looks like `ACD 000     2015 04 09   14:00` now.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily use `DateTime.Parse` for this purpose.

```
DateTime.Parse("9/05/2015").ToString("yyyy MM dd")
```

**Result**

> 2015 05 09

**File reading/writing example:**

This will convert a file, where each line contains a date.

```
string newLines = File.ReadAllLines(sourcePath)
    .Select(line => DateTime.Parse(line).ToString("yyyy MM dd")
    .ToArray();

File.WriteAllLines(destPath, newLines);
```

Comment: Great. But Where I should paste it to? I want to read .txt edit and save .txt. in same format.

Comment: You iterate through the lines of the text file and pass the line to `Parse()` and the write the result of `ToString()` to your file.

Comment: Is it applicable to my file? Edited question up.

Comment: No. `DateTime.Parse` will only accept a `DateTime` without any extra string.

Comment: I have added new note to my question /on the top/. There is an example of a file code.

Answer (score 1):

```
       try this,   

     string line;
        string pattern = "([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})";
        string replacement = "$3 $2 $1";

        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
           Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
          if (rgx.Matches(line).Count > 0)
          {
           var s = rgx.Matches(line)[0].ToString(); 
           var parts = s.Split(new[] {'/'});
           if (parts[0].Length == 1)
            {
                replacement = "$3 $2 0$1";
            }
            else if(parts[0].Lenght==2)
            {
                replacement = "$3 $2 $1";
            }
          }
           string result = rgx.Replace(line, replacement);
           all += result + "\r\n";
           richTextBox1.Text += result + "\r\n";
        }
```

Comment: you have one date in each line?

Comment: could you please write one line of your sample?

Comment: There are many rows with many words. ANd sometime there is a date.  Example: ACD 000     9/04/2015   14:00 



REPT 1
ACD      AVG CALLS       AVG  AVG  AVG  AVG  AVG    DN  AVG   #-XFER  AVG-TIME-POSN 
 DN     AGTS ANSWD  ASA  DCP HDCP  PCP WORK WAIT CALLS TIME  IDN  ACD   BUSY MANNED
7777       1     3   15   91    0   82  173  477     4   96    0    0    453   1169

Comment: After debug: line var s = rgx.Matches(line)[0].ToString(); throw ArgumentOutOffRange

Comment: sorry, this is my fault. please check again.

Comment: It works when there is 1 digit. But when there are 2 digits, it shows: 010, 021 etc... :(